# Is there a simple way I could create an effect when my mouse touches a div in HTML, css or javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to reproduce this effect, whenever the mouse touches a div, the div get surrounded by some sort of container like this

[image]

Please any idea how I could archive this. A demo can be found at https://io.google/2022/ on the grow your skill section.

Comment: you mean like, when the mouse "`:hover`s" over an element adding a `border`, or maybe an `outline` to the element, with maybe a `radius` on the `border` to make the corners rounded?

Comment: hey @Bravo can u maybe give me rough css sketch to start with, thanks

Comment: so, the selector would include `:hover` to be effective only on hover, and the properties would include `outline:  ????;` where ???? is whatever you want your outline to look like (you can use `border:` instead if you want) and, regardless if it's an outline or a border, you'll want a  `border-radius:` property to set the radius of the outline/border for the rounded corners

Comment: thank you. surprisingly got in on the first trial

Comment: I gave you the ingredients to make a ham sandwich, and you made a ham sandwich - that's not surprising - what would've been surprising would be if I gave you those ingredients, and you made a helicopter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:hover` with border, outline and border radius for this to happen

heres the CSS:

```css
.container:hover{
   border: 1px solid white;
   border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Also make sure to add a regular border in the container or if we hover, it has to create new borders that can cause it to jump from its place

Just add a transparent border:

```css
.container {
   border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```